# UIWebView's baseURL set to NSDocumentDirectory?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to set the baseURL of a UIWebView to NSDocumentDirectory? If yes, how does one do that?

What I'm trying to do is to display some downloaded images locally in the /img src=""/ tag.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To load your local file inside webview do the following

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *HTMLData = @"
<img src="YOUR_IMAGE.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" />";

[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];
```

This should load YOUR_IMAGE.jpg inside the UIWebView
read more from 
http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/loading-local-files-into-uiwebview/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm trying to accomplish, I wasn't specific enough. I'd like to display an image from the NSDocumentDirectory in a local HTML file, in other words - set the src="" to the path of the file in user's document directory. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do what this person did: [UIWebView: Absolute path for images in app documents folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237420/uiwebview-absolute-path-for-images-in-app-documents-folder)

Basically, it uses the document directory path for the image source, and not simply img src="image_name"